# OpenERP 7: Why inherited view isn't display?

Tags: inheritance, view, odoo, openerp-7

I'm trying to override the `Deliver` button from the Delivery Orders view (i.e. `stock.picking.out`) and the one in the related wizard (i.e. `stock.partial.picking`).

To do that I've created a custom module: *compose_delivery_order*.

#### *deliver_button.xml*

as [a gist](https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/82a1457e484d5ccb1969/79ff2e47503e36c0370e1eff07edc4db86114efd)

```xml
<data>
    <!-- override: stock/wizard/stock_partial_picking_view.xml -->
    <record id="stock_partial_picking_delivery_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">compose_delivery_order.stock_partial_picking_delivery_form</field>
        <field name="model">stock.partial.picking</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="15"/>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.stock_partial_picking_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="/form/footer//button[@name='do_partial']" position="replace">
                <button
                        name="do_partial"
                        string="picking delivery"
                        type="object"
                        class="oe_highlight"
                />
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    <!-- override: sale_stock/sale_stock_view.xml -->
    <record id="view_delivery_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">stock.picking.out.form</field>
        <field name="model">stock.picking.out</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_out_form"/>
        <field name="view_id" ref="stock_partial_picking_delivery_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="/form/header//button[@name='action_process']" position="replace">
                <button name="action_process" states="assigned" string="[Deliver]" type="object"
                        class="oe_highlight"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
```

#### Issue

The button on `stock.picking.out` is correctly replace, but the one in `stock.partial.picking` is not. When I check the *Manage Views* info I got:

[image: detected but not used]

So my view is detected but not selected as the default one it seems.

#### Question

How can I force the use of my view?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways of referencing views in Odoo :

> 1. if a view is requested by (model, type), the view with the right
>      model and type, mode=primary and the lowest priority is matched
> 2. when a view is requested by id, if its mode is not primary its
>      closest parent with mode primary is matched

If your view is requested by priority then try setting priority to a lower value.

Comment: As you can see I already tried to change the priority, without success.

Comment: give it a lower value 5 for example instead of 15. as the lowest priority is the one matched

Comment: see my answer, in my case it had nothing to do with priority as the button was overridden in python code.

Comment: I see. Then you need to define a new action for your view then call your new action from the button

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, try and test I finally discover that the button for the given **view was overridden in python code**.

So to modify the button, I had to override the method in my module

```py
# override: stock/wizard/stock_partial_picking.py
class stock_partial_picking(osv.osv_memory):
    _inherit = 'stock.partial.picking'
    _rec_name = 'picking_id'
    _description = "Partial Picking Processing Wizard"

    def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        # override of fields_view_get in order to change the label of the process button and the separator accordingly to the shipping type
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        res = super(stock_partial_picking, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type,
                                                                 context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
        type = context.get('default_type', False)
        if type:
            doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
            for node in doc.xpath("//button[@name='do_partial']"):
                if type == 'in':
                    node.set('string', _('_Receive'))
                elif type == 'out':
                    node.set('string', _('[_Deliver]'))
            for node in doc.xpath("//separator[@name='product_separator']"):
                if type == 'in':
                    node.set('string', _('Receive Products'))
                elif type == 'out':
                    node.set('string', _('Deliver Products'))
            res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
        return res
```